# Better way of adding elements from a parsed XML to a dict when unsure of what attributes it contains

Tags: python

Sorry for titlegore. But my problem is quite "simple". I have this:

```
if "unit" in pin.attrib:
    test_dict["pins"].append({
        "type": pin.attrib["type"],
        "unit": pin.attrib["unit"], 
        "name":pin.text
    })
else:
    test_dict["pins"].append({
        "type": pin.attrib["type"],
        "name":pin.text
    })
```

Since not all elements have the attribute ["unit"]. This way gets very cumbersome if there are multiple attributes (or combination of them) to check.

(basically what I want is something like:

psudoode:

```
    test_dict["pins"].append({
        "type": pin.attrib["type"],
        if "unit" in pin.attrib: "unit": pin.attrib["unit"], 
        "name":pin.text
    })
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
test_dict["pins"].append(dict(
    {'name': pin.text},
    **{k: pin.attrib[k] for k in ['type', 'unit'] if k in pin.attrib}
))
```

On [python3.5+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) you can use this syntax :

```
test_dict["pins"].append({
    ** {k: pin.attrib[k] for k in ['type', 'unit'] if k in pin.attrib},
    "name": pin.text
})
```

Comment: Never seen this syntax. What does **{} do? Thanks!

Comment: It is a [keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument). More infos [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments). And [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) you can see that dict constructor can take both mapping and keyword arguments : `class dict(mapping, **kwarg)`